# Iterating through JSON data from external API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a function `return_summoner_champion_list(name)` that will return the following JSON data when called

```
[
  {
    "id"=>"1",
    "name"=>"A"
  },
  {
    "id"=>"2",
    "name"=>"B"
  },
  and so on...
]
```

How do I iterate through the JSON array and print out all ids?

I tried

```
return_summoner_champion_list(name).each do |list|
  puts list["id"]
end
```

but it still returns the same JSON data as above without any changes.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's an array of hashes. Iterate through it like you would an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think you're looking for `Array#collect` not `Array#each`:

```
return_summoner_champion_list(name).collect{|l| l['id']}
=> [1,2, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your method returning JSON or an Ruby array? If it is indeed returning JSON, first convert that to an array with `JSON.parse()`, and then work with the array that is returned.